# Sentence tokenization using NLTK package in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, nltk

I have a table like below one:

| Name | comment |
| --- | --- |
| Mike | Mikes comment one. Mr.Mikes comment 2. Mikes comment 3 |
| Jack | Mr.Jacks comment one. Jacks comment 2... e.g This is example |

I want the output like below:

| Name | comment |
| --- | --- |
| Mike | Mikes comment one. |
| Mike | Mr.Mikes comment 2 |
| Mike | Mikes comment 3 |
| Jack | Mr.Jacks comment one |
| Jack | Jacks comment 2 |
| Jack | e.g This is example |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`nltk.sent_tokenize`](https://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tokenize.html) with [`DataFrame.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html):

```
import nltk

df['comment'] = df['comment'].apply(nltk.sent_tokenize)

df = df.explode('comment')
print (df)
   Name                                 comment
0  Mike                      Mikes comment one.
0  Mike                     Mr.Mikes comment 2.
0  Mike                         Mikes comment 3
1  Jack                   Mr.Jacks comment one.
1  Jack  Jacks comment 2... e.g This is example
```